# Cosmos DB Error: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 11: 'Database account is not found'

Tags: mongodb, authentication, ssl, azure-cosmosdb

I have created a Cosmos DB(with Mongo API) in my azure subscription.

now trying to connect to CosmosDB using my existing code to connect to mongo DB. i just change the code to create mongo client.

i created the Mongo Client using connectionstring i got from Cosmos DB -> connection strings.

the same thing works with the Cosmos DB provided by microsoft for trial. 
it can be created from https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/try/cosmosdb.

but it does not work with the Cosmos DB i created in my subscription.

i get below errors:

```
com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=null, userName='[myusername]', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties={}}
at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.wrapInMongoSecurityException(SaslAuthenticator.java:157) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar:?]
at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.access$200(SaslAuthenticator.java:37) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar:?]
at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:66) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar:?]
at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:44) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar:?]
at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.doAsSubject(SaslAuthenticator.java:162) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar:?]
at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslAuthenticator.java:44) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar:?]
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultAuthenticator.authenticate(DefaultAuthenticator.java:32) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar:?]
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.authenticateAll(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:109) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar:?]
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:46) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar:?]
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:116) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar:?]
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:113) [mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_171]


Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 11: 'Database account is not found' on server [my cosmosdb name].documents.azure.com:10255. The full response is { "_t" : "OKMongoResponse", "ok" : 0, "code" : 11, "errmsg" : "Database account is not found", "$err" : "Database account is not found" }
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.createCommandFailureException(CommandHelper.java:170) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.receiveCommandResult(CommandHelper.java:123) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:32) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.sendSaslContinue(SaslAuthenticator.java:121) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.access$100(SaslAuthenticator.java:37) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:63) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar:?]
    ... 9 more
```

**am i missing any configurations on my azure portal???**

Comment: i tried after removing firewall and it works.... how to make this work with security enabled?

Comment: What kind of security are you enabling? Are you adding IP Filtering? If so, is your local IP within that filter?

Comment: i added by local ip in firewall exception

Comment: Firewall configurations can take a couple of minutes to apply, that's the only thing that I can think of. Or you are going through some proxy that is changing your actual Outbound IP.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable your firewall but that would leave you very exposed. Better enable the access to your workstation:

1. Go to your Azure Cosmos DB menu called **Firewall and virtual networks**.

[image: Firewall and virtual networks]

2. Choose Selected networks
3. Click the suggested option **+ Add my current IP (xx.xx.xx.xx)** which basically automatically adds the Internet IP of your workstation to the allowed client IPs your MongoDB/CosmosDB.
4. Go to your Azure Cosmos DB menu called **Quick start**. There you will be provided with alternatives of connection to your database.